# Database connection for JDBC request on jmeter

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, data-connections

For JDBC request on Jmeter I have configured properly Database Connection Configuration with giving

**Database Url**- jdbc:mysql://developmentdb.cwwxeukesrtn.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com;Development_DB

**JDBC Driver** Class- com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

**Username**-...

**Password**-...

then I create a JDBC request with Select Statementbut after run this request,on the response message got this message-

Response message:

> java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the
>   server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets
>   from the server.)

Now my question is , how to solve this problem?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**You need two basic things to get that done**:

1. Tunneling
2. *mysql.jdbc* jar in `JMeter` lib folder.

---

For 1st:

1. Open Putty
2. Go to Connection >> SSH >> Tunnels
3. Put down the details as port: 9876
4. Put down the details as database URL (present in the application config file), e.g:

   ```
   jdbc:mysql://developmentdb.cwwxeukesrtn.ap-southeast-.rds.amazonaws.com;Development_DB
   ```
5. Add it

   [image: Stack]
6. Open *JMeter >> Add JDBC Connection Configuration*
7. Use DataBase URL as `jdbc:mysql://localhost:9876` and the
   other details as shown in the picture, like *JDBC driver Class*

   [image: JDBC]

For step 2. Go through this link:
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mysql-database-and-jmeter-how-to-test-your-connection/

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [Driver/Datasource Class Names, URL Syntax and Configuration Properties for Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) article:

[image: JDBC URL Format]

I believe you need to replace the semicolon before `Development_DB` with a slash like:

```
jdbc:mysql://developmentdb.cwwxeukesrtn.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com/Development_DB
```

For more information on databases load testing see [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) article.

---

You might also need to open port 3306 in your operating system firewall and add the relevant [Security Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html) to your instance in order to allow MySQL JDBC traffic.